# NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification after insertion

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsnotificationcenter

When i add a new `NSManagedObject` instance to the `NSManagedObjectContext` like this:

```
NSManagedObject *newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Bla" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[newObject setValue:@"New Object" forKey:@"name"];
```

i get **1** `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` with a `NSInsertedObjectsKey` and as the new value the "name" value "New Object".

I would expect to get:

- 1 `InsertedObjectKey` notification with new value of "name" = nil
- 1 `UpdatedObjectKey` notification with new value of "name" = "New Object"

I have the feeling this is a feature, but i'm note sure..

Comment: The question is: Am i missing something? Is this a feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed object contexts bunch together their changes. You don't get notified for every single value change, but instead periodically at the end of each "lump" of changes.

If you particularly want a notification for each change separately, in the above code you could call -processPendingChanges in between

Answer (score 3):

In the [NSManagedObjectContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) it says under `insertedObjects`

> A managed object context does not post key-value observing notifications when the return value of insertedObjects changes—it does, however, post a NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification notification when a change is made, and a NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification and a NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification notification before and after changes are committed respectively.